# View's content appearing differently

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm almost ready to publish my first app into the Play Store but I can't do it until I fix an annoying graphic thing: when I'm writing code and building graphics every single element (buttons, textviews, listviews etc.) is where I want it to be. But when I emulate the app on a Samsung S3 (GT-i9300) every element moves some dip's to the left, creating very messy views.

I'm using the attribute `<support-screens>` into the manifest and I have different resources for the different screens (hdpi-ldpi etc.).
What should I do?

EDIT: this is a sample layout. As you can see everything has its own place (camera button at center, send button on the left etc.) but when I emulate the app on the S3 everything floats to the left... For example: the last button is set to have a marginleft=140dip but when the app is running on the S3 it goes something like 40dip to the left of the view...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:background="@drawable/paperback">
  <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


          <!-- Form di registrazione android:background="#fff" android:background="#E1DFF4"-->

          <!-- Fine Form di Registrazione -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Titolo"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/titolo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Articolo"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/articolo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imview"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/insert"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
                android:background="@drawable/camera" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dip" >

                 <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Invia"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dip"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dip"                     
                     android:layout_gravity="right"
                     android:text="Condividi"
                     android:textColor="#372c24" />

                  </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/insart"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:background="@drawable/youtube_dark"/>

             <Button
                android:id="@+id/fb"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="140dip"
                android:background="@drawable/share_dark"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

No one?!

Comment: Can you post some short samples of layouts that are not appearing as you expect them to?

Comment: for sure. I'm updating my question :)